# Split data into a multiple row

Tags: sql, sql-server

| Unitnumber | Number |
| --- | --- |
| #201-12/14 | 1 |
| #101-34to 37 | 2 |
| #01-112, #01-K106 & #01-113/114 | 4 |

Output:

| Unitnumber | Number |
| --- | --- |
| #201-12 | 1 |
| #201-13 | 1 |
| #201-14 | 1 |
| #101-34 | 2 |
| #101-35 | 2 |
| #101-36 | 2 |
| #101-37 | 2 |
| #01-112 | 4 |
| #01-K106 | 4 |
| #01-113 | 4 |
| #01-114 | 4 |

I used the string_split function but it's not useful.

In sql server, I want to split a data such as #101-33to 37

so my output will be

#101-33

#101-34

#101-35

#101-36

#101-37

Comment: Please do not use images and if you can provide repeatable example you will get help much easier/faster:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This is not really a split, but rather generate_series kind of question, but it's also 3 questions in one, since the splitting logic is different. I suggest "splitting" your question into several

Comment: Consumable sample data, and expected results, **not** an image, will help us help you.

Comment: @Brad, I edit a question with table format as you want

Comment: The biggest issue here is your input data is a disaster. Are the only two range delimiters `/` and `to`? Can there be others? Is it possible to fix the source of this data instead? Also, what version of sql server are you using?

Comment: The initial table is a **broken** schema design, so there won't be a trivial way to do this in SQL. The output is how it _should_ have been built in the first place.

Comment: I would commend the OP for taking on the task of taking sub-par data and mapping it to a more normalized form.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

This will work with your sample data assuming you are using sql server 2022, or Azure. There are ways to make this work with older versions of sql server but it is even more hurdles to come up with a solution as the string_split doesn't return the ordinal position and generate_series doesn't exist until 2022. This is extremely brittle and very likely to break as I am guessing your source data is just free text.

That being said this will work with your sample data to produce the output you stated you want.

```
create table #Something
(
    Unitnumber varchar(50)
    , Number int
)
insert #Something values
('#201-12/14', 1)
, ('#101-34to 37', 2)
;

with parsedValues as
(
    select *
    from #Something s
    cross apply string_split(s.Unitnumber, '-', 1) x
)
, prefix as
(
    select Unitnumber = pv.Unitnumber 
        , prefix = pv.value
    from parsedValues pv
    where pv.ordinal = 1
)
, rangeEndPoints as
(
    select pv.Unitnumber
        , SeriesStart = min(x.value)
        , SeriesEnd = max(x.value)
    from parsedValues pv
    cross apply string_split(replace(pv.value, 'to ', '/'), '/', 1) x --this changes the delimiter "to" into "/" so they are all the same delimiter
    where pv.ordinal = 2
    group by pv.Unitnumber
)

select pv.value + '-' + convert(varchar(10), x.value)
    , pv.Number
from prefix p 
join rangeEndPoints rep on rep.Unitnumber = p.Unitnumber
cross apply generate_series(try_convert(int, rep.SeriesStart), try_convert(int, rep.SeriesEnd), 1) x
join parsedValues pv on pv.Unitnumber = p.Unitnumber and pv.ordinal = 1
order by pv.Unitnumber
    , x.value

drop table #Something
```

Comment: it's working for two rows and I have edited a question now I want a output like this for third rows(Unitnumber)

Comment: @AebdDr that is on you. The amount of effort required to modify what I did to what you changed this to is not trivial. But if you understand the code I posted you should be able to do that. It will require splitting your strings on multiple delimiters for each section. My guess is that once that requirement is met there will be more.